# Data load from blob storage to sql data warehouse using azure databricks scala

Tags: scala, azure, azure-databricks

I am trying load the data into SQL datawarehouse  from blob storage using azure databricks scala.

```
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.parquet.writeLegacyFormat","true")    
df.write.format("com.databricks.spark.sqldw")
.option("url",sqlDwUrlSmall)
.option("dbtable", "Person")        
.option("forward_spark_azure_storage_credentials","True")
.option("tempdir",tempDir).mode("overwrite").save()
```

I am getting this error

> Underlying SQLException(s):
>     - com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: External file access failed due to internal error: 'Error occurred while accessing
>   HDFS: Java exception raised on call to HdfsBridge_IsDirExist. Java
>   exception message: HdfsBridge::isDirExist - Unexpected error
>   encountered checking whether directory exists or not:
>   StorageException: This request is not authorized to perform this
>   operation.' [ErrorCode = 105019] [SQLState = S0001]

Comment: i am using access key to get the data from blob storage

Answer (score 0):

To successfully load the data from blob storage to sql data warehouse using azure databricks scala.

- Make sure are passing the correct path.
- Make sure to pass the "tempDir" as shown in the below format.

> **tempDir = "wasbs://" + blobContainer + "@" + blobStorage +"/tempDirs"**

**Reference:** [Load data into Azure SQL Data Warehouse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-databricks/databricks-extract-load-sql-data-warehouse#load-data-into-azure-sql-data-warehouse)

Hope this helps.